# Obtain job id from a workflow run using contexts

Tags: github-actions, github-api

I have a problem, when I want to get the job id using the GitHub context in yaml file, it responds with a String:

```
  - name: Test
    run: |
      sendEmail ${{github.job]}
```

I obtain this response:

```
sendEmail Job_Test
```

In the GitHub documentation for the API, it says the following, which is an Integer field:
[image]

But, in the documentation of the contexts it says that it is String:
[image]

My question is, what is it or how could I obtain the context to obtain the job id, the integer value?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no straight way to do that - those are not the same values.

The only solution I know is to:

1. read `github.job` getting the key
2. get list of jobs for a workflow using API: `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs/{run_id}/jobs`
3. find the job by the name and get id as int value

Comment: Unfortunately if the job contains matrix strategy it becomes impossible to find the right id. For example job1 is started for ubuntu-latest and ubuntu-20.04. In both cases github.job is job1, but two separate jobs are created for them :/

Answer (score 7):

There's a GitHub action to solve this problem: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-actions-job_id-parser

```
 - name: Get Current Job Log URL
    uses: Tiryoh/gha-jobid-action@v0
    id: jobs
    with:
      github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      job_name: ${{ github.job }}

- name: Output Current Job Log URL
  run: echo ${{ steps.jobs.outputs.html_url }}
```

Comment: This only works for very simple cases. If you've got a matrix or the workflow is called from another workflow it's not straight forward to get the job_name and the action will fail.

Answer (score 6):

This information is not available in the github context level, however you can just filter out it, using a unique job information, like the runner.name. In this way you can get job id for any case, including matrix.

```
  - name: Get Job ID from GH API
    id: get-job-id
    env:
      GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    run: |
      jobs=$(gh api repos/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id}}/attempts/${{ github.run_attempt }}/jobs)
      job_id=$(echo $jobs | jq -r '.jobs[] | select(.runner_name=="${{ runner.name }}") | .id')
      echo "job_id=$job_id" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  - name: Display Job ID
    run: |
      echo Job ID: ${{ steps.get-job-id.outputs.job_id }}
      echo My full job URL is ${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id }}/job/${{ steps.get-job-id.outputs.job_id }}
```

Comment: The `runner.name` trick did the job great even when using a matrix strategy. Indeed `github.job` cannot work because on matrix strategy, the job name is actually appended with some element of the matrix strategy so you don't get the right now.

Comment: Unfortunately, as much as I wish this was a working solution, `runner.name` is **not** a "a unique job information" as stated in this answer. See the [GitHub Actions docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#runner-context): "`runner.name` - The name of the runner executing the job. This name **may not be unique** in a workflow run (...)".

So it seems the only reliable way remains to find the job by its `name` - https://github.com/Tiryoh/gha-jobid-action can do this for you, you just need to provide correct `job_name` (works for matrix jobs too, see README).

Comment: I verified the non-uniqueness of runner IDs/names in practice by [querying the GitHub REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-jobs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-jobs-for-a-workflow-run) for a workflow run with 41 jobs - although all jobs had some `runner_name`, there were only 20 unique runner names in total, which matches the maximum number of concurrent jobs in the GitHub Free plan (this makes sense - more than 20 jobs are not allowed run concurrently, so it seems that when a runner finishes one job, it gets another one from the queue - hence the repeating runner IDs).

Comment: Solid foundation here, which I used as a basis for my [proposed solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78171197/8377918) using native github-script's context and applicable for matrices of any size/order.

Answer (score 1):

Job ID may be obtained with `curl` command (piped to `jq`):

```bash
curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}/actions/runs/${GITHUB_RUN_ID}/attempts/${GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT}/jobs | jq .jobs[].id
```

where all ENVs `GITHUB_*` should be accessible inside workflow by default

PS `jobs` value is list so multiple IDs may be returned

Answer (score 1):

for a matrix strategy, although not pretty this will get the html url to the proper matrix job (in this example, the "name" of each individual matrix job is `matrix.region`): `gh api repos/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id}}/attempts/${{ github.run_attempt }}/jobs | jq -r '.jobs | map(select(.name | contains("${{ matrix.region }}"))) | .[0].html_url'`.  example:

```
 example-job:
    name: ${{ matrix.region }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        region: ["us-east-1", "us-west-2"]
      - name: example-matrix-step
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          job_id=$(gh api repos/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id}}/attempts/${{ github.run_attempt }}/jobs | jq -r '.jobs | .[0].id')
          matrix_job_html_url=$(gh api repos/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.run_id}}/attempts/${{ github.run_attempt }}/jobs | jq -r '.jobs | map(select(.name | contains("${{ matrix.region }}"))) | .[0].html_url')
          matrix_id=$( sed 's/.*\jobs\///' <<<$matrix_job_html_url)
          echo "matrix job html url: $matrix_job_html_url"
          echo "matrix id: $matrix_id" # i doubt this is of any use. in the github response this id is only present as part of the html_url
          echo "job id: $job_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

While it'd be ideal to have a separate `github.job_id` alongside the existing [`github.job`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context:%7E:text=pull_request_target.-,github.job,-string), the main challenges here are:

1. Obtainable from contexts alone.
2. Compatible with matrix strategy (without hard-coding).

Most of the answers here fall short of handling matrices, so here's my working solution to this which leverages native [actions/github-script](https://github.com/actions/github-script)'s context.

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Resolve job ID from workflow run, accounting for matrix strategy.
    id: job_id
    uses: actions/github-script@main
    env:
      matrix: ${{ toJson(matrix) }}
    with:
      script: |
        const { data: workflow_run } = await github.rest.actions.listJobsForWorkflowRun({
          owner: context.repo.owner,
          repo: context.repo.repo,
          run_id: context.runId
        });
        const matrix = JSON.parse(process.env.matrix);
        const job_name = `${context.job}${matrix ? ` (${Object.values(matrix).join(", ")})` : ""}`;
        return workflow_run.jobs.find((job) => job.name === job_name).id;

  - name: Print job ID
    run: echo "${{ steps.job_id.outputs.result }}"
```

Of note:

- Obtain context from [octokit/rest.js](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v20#actions-list-jobs-for-workflow-run)'s `rest.actions.listJobsForWorkflowRun`, as documented in [REST API endpoints](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-jobs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-jobs-for-a-workflow-run).
- If [`matrix`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context:%7E:text=pull_request_target.-,github.job,-string) context is present, represent it as a comma-separated string of values (e.g., convert `{ "os": "ubuntu-latest", "node": 20 }` to `ubuntu-latest, 20`).
- Surround this string in `()` parentheses then append to `context.job` using a ternary operator, enabling it to work with or without a matrix of any size/order.
- Return the associated ID matching the job name for use/reference in later steps.

Answer (score 0):

I gave the `Tiryoh/gha-jobid-action` action a try, but it requires the runner to have `jq` and `curl` installed. I prefer something a bit more independent, without the need to do any additional `apt-get` commands for containers without either of those.

So I made my own, borrowing much of the technique, and mimicking the same inputs/outputs.

[daleyjem/gh-job-id@v1](https://github.com/daleyjem/gh-job-id)