# Github Actions : How do you retrieve the runtime Job ID within a WF?

Tags: yaml, github-actions

In a GitHub Actions WF YAML file, how do we retrieve the runtime Job ID?

The following snippet returns the Run ID and the Job Name but not able to retrieve the Job ID:

```
P_JOBNAME=${{ github.job }}
P_RUNID=${{ github.run_id }}
```

Comment: JobID is the job name see: [`job_id`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_id) is that what you need? Or what number you are referring to as id?

Comment: [`github.job`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) gives the job ID, not job name.

Comment: What are you expecting the `Job ID` to be? As noted by the other comments, `github.job` is the `job_id` of the current job which is a string you assigned in your workflow. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_id

Comment: To retrieve the runtime Job ID within a GitHub Actions workflow, you can use the `github` context and the `job` context. Therefore, I understand that what you're looking for may be achieved by using: `${{ github.run_id }}` and `${{ job.id }}`

Comment: @GuiFalourd: The [`job` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#job-context) doesn't have an `id`. It's listed here under [`jobs.<job_id>.name`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idname) and according to [`jobs` context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#jobs-context), it "**is only available in reusable workflows, and can only be used to set outputs for a reusable workflow**".

Comment: Further to the responses , the ````{{ github.job }}```` or ````{{github.job.id}}````  will return the name of the job which the static string you define in your workflow. 

However what I am looking for is a specific Job id i.e. how do I get the ````7430887182 ```` number in a run log pertaining to a single job , whose output URL will look like this. 

````https://github.com/<your repo>/actions/runs/4268412017/jobs/7430887182````

Comment: @ChzDz: Where is that `github.job.id` coming from? Could you please share the reference? I could not find it in the docs nor did it work during my testing. Adding it issues a warning as `job` is a string here i.e. `github.job` and not an object. See [this](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJw1jTsOgzAQRHufYgpacwCfA4kaByd2MLuI3VUKxN35JOlGem9maJhTQM/r9Kz8cUwBi0l2b44SHBCt1PEKwGok/hIsGqn5OmgSvZFoWuRrAR50j3Z/+isHpEdmNNuGV9FssT1P2jJi3w8ScSlJ).

Comment: @Azeem ````github.job.id```` returns the job name , got it from one of the comments. 

Objective : When you run deployments by the hundreds, we log these ID's in a table so that later we can build up the specific log URL for that run + job combo to be retrieved. 

Navigating through the GitHub UI is clunky and not possible.

Comment: @ChzDz: Could you please show a small example of how you're using it with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/? Thanks! Also, during my testing with the [`gh run view`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_run_view) command e.g. `gh run view --repo <REPO> --json jobs --jq '.jobs[].name' <RUN_ID>`, `jobs` is an array and contains a `name` field which actually provides the job name if it exists, it contains the Job ID otherwise which is the YAML key.

Comment: @Azeem sorry I am new and not familiar with rhysd.github.io/actionlint?
i.e. how to send the output ..
here is the code 
````---
name: stack1
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Test
        shell: bash
        run: |
          echo "Job id : " ${{ github.job }}
          echo "Run id : " ${{ github.run_id }}
````

Comment: @ChzDz: No worries. In your pasted workflow, `github.job.id` is not present.

Comment: it doesn't matter , actually I am just looking for a way to retrieve the Job ID value for a specific run :-D 

Another strange finding is , if you rerun a specific Job , then in that Job code the ````{{ github.run_id }}```` does not return any value. 
I understand the id will be the same as the prev one since you are re-running it. But why is it not returning the value ?

Comment: @ChzDz: Right. Not sure. You might want to take into account the `github.run_number` and `github.run_attempt` too. See the [`github`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) context for their details. Apart from that, looks like this question is already answered in the comments i.e. `github.job` gives the job ID. You might want to self-answer this. Thanks!

Comment: @Azeem,
Thanks for the ````github.run_attempt```` and ````github.run_number```` these are useful. 
However the ````github.job```` just gives the job name, not the job_id which gets dynamically generated with each run. It is this value that I am looking for. 

```` 
jobs:
  ConnectPPMDev:
    runs-on: ppm-prod-runner1
    steps:
      - name: Step1 - in WF
        run: |
          echo "Executing Job"
          echo "github.job_id : " ${{ github.job_id }}
          echo "github.job : " ${{ github.job }}
```` 
Prints 

github.job_id : 
github.job :  ConnectPPMDev

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obtain job id from a workflow run using contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71240338/obtain-job-id-from-a-workflow-run-using-contexts)